# Changing product name with mage.exe

Tags: continuous-integration, clickonce, publish, mage

I need to update the application's [manifest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_%28CLI%29) with a new value for 'product'. With `mage.exe` I can update the name and publisher but NOT the product. In [MageUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55.aspx) you can do this, but I need to do it on the commandline.

Is there a solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I played around and it seems the command line tool indeed lacks this capability. I guess it was done for keeping it lightweight (or maybe cost issues).

Alternative would be to use the [GenerateApplicationManifest MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wc2ccdc.aspx):

**Example:**

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <GenerateApplicationManifest
        AssemblyName="myapp.exe"
        Product="My Product"
        ...
        OutputManifest="SimpleWinApp.exe.manifest">
        <Output
            ItemName="ApplicationManifest"
            TaskParameter="OutputManifest"/>
    </GenerateApplicationManifest>
</Target>
```

This gives you lot more options (in fact everything that you can do through `MageUI`, can be done from here) and you bypass `mage.exe` (and its limitations) totally.

You should be able to use it anywhere MSBuild is supported (csproj files, TFS Build proj files etc).

Comment: Yes you can. Check out this excellent post here: [Integrating MSBuild with CruiseControl.NET](http://www.dougrohm.com/blog/post/Integrating-MSBuild-with-CruiseControlNET.aspx)

Comment: @Martin: Don't forget to award the bounty!

Comment: This doesn't seem right. I've been trying to change the name of the app (in the start menu and when installing), and finally got it to work by specifying the -Name option when creating the *deployment* manifest (this is in a .Net 4 environment so may be different now?). The relevant part of the deployment manifest is the 'product' attribute on the 'description' element.

Comment: can this also change the assemblyname