# Force GenerateApplicationManifest to run in MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild, clickonce, manifest, publish

My requirement is to change the ProductName in the application manifest file. I did the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595304/changing-product-name-with-mage-exe), but for me, the product name still doesn't change. In the log, I can see that the `GenerateApplicationManifest` task is not getting executed. The log says:

```
Skipping target "GenerateApplicationManifest" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
```

But I want this task to run, so that the product name is changed. This is the code.

```
<DeployEXE>The application .exe file</DeployEXE>
<DeployManifest>The .exe.manifest file</DeployManifest>
<AppManifest>The .application file</AppManifest>

Line 1: <Exec Command="$(Msbuild) $(ClientAppProject) /t:Clean;Publish /p:BootstrapperEnabled=true;UpdateRequired=true;MinimumRequiredVersion=$(Version);UpdateEnabled=true;UpdateMode=Foreground;UpdateInterval=7;UpdateIntervalUnits=Days;UpdatePeriodically=false;PublishDir=$(PublishDir);ApplicationVersion=$(Version);PublisherName=&quot;$(PublisherName)&quot;;ProductName=&quot;$(ClickOnceAppTitle)&quot;;PublishUrl=$(ClickOnceUrl);GenerateManifests=true;Install=true;Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU"/>

Line 2: <Exec Command="$(SN) -R $(DeployEXE) $(SNKFile)"/>

Line 3: <Exec Command="$(MAGE) -UPDATE $(DeployManifest) -CertFile $(CertFile) -Password $(Password) -pub &quot;$(PublisherName)&quot; -UseManifestForTrust t" />

Line 4: <Exec Command="$(MAGE) -UPDATE $(AppManifest) -AppManifest $(DeployManifest) -CertFile $(CertFile) -Password $(Password) -pub &quot;$(PublisherName)&quot; -UseManifestForTrust t"/>

Line 5: <GenerateApplicationManifest
            AssemblyName="$(EXEName).exe"
            Product="$(ClickOnceAppTitle)"
            EntryPoint="$(EXEName).exe"
            OutputManifest="$(EXEName).exe.manifest">
            <Output
                ItemName="ApplicationManifest"
                TaskParameter="OutputManifest"/>
        </GenerateApplicationManifest>
```

After `Line 1`, I can see the correct publisher & product names set in the .application & .exe.manifet files (eg: PublisherName is set to `MyCompany`, ProductName is set to `My Company Software`). After `Line 4` is executed, the publisher name stays correct, but the product name is then replaced with the assembly name (eg: ProductName changes to `My.Company.Software`). For correcting this, I've added `Line 5`, which ideally should have corrected the ProductName, but it doesn't happen.

What could be the problem here? Why is this task ignored by MSBUILD?

Comment: Which target did you add this task into? Could you copy full code you added to the project file?

Comment: Your confusion here is that the MSBuild does not execute *target* called `GenerateApplicationManifest`. Notice that targets and tasks are different concepts. MSBuild never skips tasks (well, unless there is a `Condition` clause in the task that is evaluated to `false`). It sounds like your task does get execute. What is going on here is that in addition to a task called `GenerateApplicationManifest`, there is a target, also called `GenerateApplicationManifest`, which is defined in Microsoft.Common.targets. This might get skipped if MSBuild finds that all outputs are up to date.

Comment: @SevaTitov: So what needs to be done here in order to get the ProductName corrected?

Comment: I would start with carefully inspecting MSBuild logs, produced with /v:diag option, making sure the task does get executed, then if needed add diagnostic <Message> tasks between task invocations to print out properties you want to confirm, and finally confirming that parameters you pass to `GenerateApplicationManifest` are correct.